# Azure B2C How to pass Culture

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Localized website that uses Azure B2C for Authentication.  I have enabled a Custom Layout just to have some Branding and have enabled English, French and Spanish in my SignIn Policy (Built-in).

I have read this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization) multiple times and I can only assume this paragraph is the answer but it means nothingto me.

> There are two ways to localize your HTML content. One way is to turn on language customization. Enabling this feature allows Azure AD B2C to forward the OpenID Connect parameter, ui-locales, to your endpoint. Your content server can use this parameter to provide customized HTML pages that are language-specific.

First, the text Language Customization int he above just links back to that same page.
Second, the sentence that follows is just gibberish to me and they don't offer an example.

Answer (score 2):

[Language customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization) allows the text strings of any page layout to be localized for one of [36 different languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#supported-languages).

For a built-in flow, for information about how to localize these text strings, see [the **Customize your strings** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#customize-your-strings).

If the page layout references your HTML content, then the current language can be passed from the built-in flow to your HTML content, using either:

1. The **ui_locales** parameter:

`https://myhtmlcontent.contoso.com/unified.html?ui_locales=fr`

2. The **{Culture:RFC5646}** placeholder:

`https://myhtmlcontent.contoso.com/{Culture:RFC5646}/unified.html`

which is replaced with:

`https://myhtmlcontent.contoso.com/fr/unified.html`